# Can a Canadian citizen go to Berlin on a one-way ticket?

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, canadian-citizens, one-way

My friend was thinking of booking last-minute trips...& I was wondering whether a Canadian citizen not born in Canada can travel to Berlin for a month with a one-way ticket and no visa? I'm not sure about when exactly I want to return...or do you need proof of return stuff?  If so, what are the list of things needed?

Comment: What you're talking about is proof of onward travel.

Comment: Canadian citizens using Canadian passports do not require a visa to enter the Schengen Area of countries in Europe for tourism or business stays under ninety (90) days.

Comment: It's playing visa roulette, as proof of onward travel to a destination outside of the zone is a requirement.

Comment: I have never been asked for proof of onward travel when entering the Schengen area as a US Citizen. That doesn't mean it couldn't happen.

Comment: @pnuts (love your name! Lol) So it must be a round trip ticket?

Comment: Note that the requirements - like every requirement relating to all visas - is **deliberately completely vague** so that countries can do what they want. In theory, having a return ticket by no means "definitely means" you have proved that you have enough money, and/or are not secretly trying to sneak in to live in the region.  As everyone has mentioned, it is extremely unlikely to be asked about your onward ticket, in europe. (Whereas - as far as I know - in the US they usually check.) BUT if you, say, look like a hippie or an illegal-overstayer, you could get grilled!

Answer (score 3):

As a Canadian citizen (your country of birth is irrelevant), you can enter and stay within the Schengen area for up to 90 days within a 180 day period. Unlike in many other countries, the Schengen immigration regulations do not require you to present a return or onward ticket to enter the Schengen area, only that you can prove means of subsistence to leave the Schengen area. Proof of financial means to buy a return ticket after arriving in Berlin is hence more than good enough.

Comment: How exactly does one show proof of being able to support oneself? By the way does Paris follow the same entrance rules?

Comment: @pnuts The exact requirements (*per* the Schengen Borders Code) is “they have sufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of the intended stay and for the return to their country of origin or transit to a third country into which they are certain to be admitted, or are in a position to acquire such means lawfully”.

Comment: @verve You need to have a predefined amount of money per day. In principle e.g. a credit card is enough, although I don't think they generally ask people who can enter without a visa to show anything. Paris should follow the same rules.